# Select query, join table which is not directly referenced via Foreign Key

Tags: sql, orm, relational-database, prisma

With Prisma, I'm trying to join an indirectly referenced table onto a query, see SQL example below which represents the basic use case.
Lets say in the example, that I want to access the companyCar table from the companyUser table. I can think of 2 ways to do this, via joining using the company table, or by directly comparing the companyId of the 2 tables

**option 1, follows foreign key references**

```
SELECT * FROM CompanyUser companyuser
JOIN Company company on company.Id = companyuser.companyId
JOIN CompanyCar companycar on companycar.companyId = company.Id
```

**option 2, does not directly follow foreign key references**

```
SELECT * FROM companyUser companyuser
JOIN CompanyCar companycar on companycar.companyId = companyuser.companyId
```

How do I solve this within the prisma framework using includes or some other mechanism?

Comment: A foreign key is not needed to join. Their purpose is to enforce data consistency.

Comment: I am aware of this, I can't seem to find a method to perform such a join using the Prisma framework without using a raw query.

Answer (score 1):

I recieved a response from one of the devs on github. See the link below stating that currently a rawQuery must be used, but this feature is an outstanding feature request.

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/14905